# Sounds in Thunar or XFCE

Tags: sound, xfce, thunar

I really like how smoothly XFCE works and prefer it to GNOME, so I would like to weigh it up a bit. ;) Is there a way to play sounds on certain system events? The most useful that comes to my mind is after finishing copying, but maybe also on deleting a file or in other circumstances like there are sounds in Mac OS X or Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Check also

Applications → Settings → Xfce 4 Settings Manager → Appearance → Settings → Event sounds → [x] Enable event sounds

for some kind of sound support

Answer (score 0):

The last time i checked xfce did not support system sounds. This might prove useful

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=853173

Answer (score 0):

@tinhead: yeah, great link and another in the thread you gave:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=3907604#post3907604

Running /usr/bin/play (#apt-get install sox) is a way to go - just like Orage uses it for alarms (on a sidenote I was wondering why orage doesn't specify sox as its dependency). There are some sound sets in the software repository
apt-cache search 'sound'
perhaps with | grep -i theme